# OpenFDA Prior Notice

Tags: openfda

Is it possible to create Prior Notices using OpenFDA?
I've search the API documentation and this forum, but haven't found any topics about this.

BR
Michael Sandström

Answer (score 0):

I am a member of the openFDA development team. Unfortunately, it is not possible to create Prior Notices using OpenFDA.